# Evernote API NoteFilter words in python

Tags: python, evernote

I try to run this code to filter notes with Evernote API for Python:

```
from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient
import evernote.edam.type.ttypes as Types
from evernote.edam.notestore.ttypes import NoteFilter, NotesMetadataResultSpec
from evernote.edam.type.ttypes import NoteSortOrder

dev_token = "mytoken"

client = EvernoteClient (token=dev_token)

noteStore = client.get_note_store()
updated_filter = NoteFilter(words="intitle : Python")
# I also try to add as shown in below commented line the words parameters
#updated_filter.words="intitle:Python"
offset = 0
max_notes = 10
result_spec = NotesMetadataResultSpec(includeTitle=True)
result_list = noteStore.findNotesMetadata(dev_token, updated_filter, offset, max_notes, result_spec)

for note in result_list.notes:
    print ("Titolo: " + note.title + " | GUUID: " + note.guid)
```

When I print the notes I have all the notes and not the only one note that has Python word inside the content.
Is this the wrong way to filter?

Thanks Alex

Comment: I'm afraid this is 'works for me'. The term I used was "intitle:Test", "intitle : Test" returned nothing for me.

Comment: Although, notably, I didn't use a sandbox account.

Comment: I'll try with Oauth to bypass sandbox and to view if in production it works.

Comment: You can get a developer key for a standard account - you just add `sandbox=False` when creating the client to get access with it.